# Orange3 Save Classifier Widget

Tags: orange

I have Orange3 installed with Python 2.7 32-bit on a Windows 10 OS.  Everything seems to work okay and I have trained a Classification Tree and now want to save the model.  When I add the Save Classifier widget and connect it to the Classification Tree, I cannot enter a File name.  I've tried retraining the model with the Save Classifier widget attached, but still nothing.  I have a Classification Tree Viewer attached and it works fine okay.  Any suggestions on how I can create a .pickle file of my Classification Tree?

Comment: Orange3 doesn't work with Python 2.7 AFAIK. You either have Python 3.4+ or Orange2 you're working with.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I have Orange 3.2 and Python 3.4.  (Which brings up another one of my questions about Python 3.5 64-bit.  I'd really like to be working with it through the Orange 3.2 GUI, but that's another problem entirely...)

I figured out how to save a .pickle file with the Save Classifier.  I "primed" the directory with a file I renamed to have the file type .pickle.  Then Save Classifier allowed me to search and find this existing .pickle file and overwrite it.  It works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to save a .pickle file with the Save Classifier. I "primed" the directory with a file I renamed to have the file type .pickle. Then the Orange Save Classifier allowed me to search and find this existing .pickle file and overwrite it. It works fine now.